# jQuery code to change the color of a character inside a Blogger label name

Tags: jquery, colors, label, symbols, blogger

How can I change the color of a symbol included in a label name in a label list? The symbol is `#`. I can't use `first-letter` because it colored the symbol and the first letter. Can I use a jQuery code?

This is the code of the label list:

```
<b:loop values='data:labels where (l =&gt; l.name contains &quot;#&quot; and l.name not contains &quot;#39;&quot;)' var='label'> 
  <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a><br/> 
</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work?

You'll need to edit the label link to add `position:relative` and then with jquery contain you search if the symbol "#" is present and if it is, the script will add another symbol "#" with a class so that with CSS, we can style the color and more important, `position: absolute` so it will be placed over the original symbol "#".

```js
$(".Label a:contains('#')").prepend('<div class="wrapper">#</div>');
```

```css
.Label a { 
  /*--/for testing purposes//-- */
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative; /*Only this part must be added to Label a*/
}

.Label .wrapper {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Label">
  <a href="#"># red</a>
  <a href="#">I green</a>
  <a href="#"># yellow</a>
  <a href="#">Not blue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't use this solution because the list isn't written by me but it's produced by the code that I posted.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you had acess to the CSS. My answer is based on that, you only have to edit the CSS and add the javascript and assuming that you already have jQuery, you can even place both into a HTML/Javascript widget... No need to edit the HTML part or the code you posted... The HTML sample I posted on my answer is just to show you how it works by running the code snippet. I was under the assumption you had access to the CSS and jQuery, if that's not the case I have no idea how to help you. Sorry.

Comment: I have access to the css but the list is the result of the code not a list written by me

Answer (score 0):

```css
.your_style {
    color: red;
}
```

```xml
<div class='helper_container'>
    <b:loop values='data:labels where (l =&gt; l.name contains &quot;#&quot; and l.name not contains &quot;#39;&quot;)' var='label'>
        <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a><br/>
    </b:loop>
</div>
```

```js
$('.helper_container a').each(function () {
    var a = $(this),
        a_txt = a.text();

    a.html(a_txt.replace(/^#/, "<span class='your_style'>#</span>"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: did you add `helper_container` div as parent? here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7gat2pq1/

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work, I don't know why. It's driving me crazy!